# How can I pass quoted value to a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure which refreshes table1 by selecting a bunch of fields from table2. The issue I have is that when I run the procedure it does not update table1. 
Here is the procedure call statement:

```
CALL `dabaseName`.`p_refresh_table1`(<{loc_id VARCHAR(5)}>);
```

So if I call the procedure like so:

```
CALL `databaseName`.`p_refresh_table1`('12');
```

or like so:

```
CALL `databaseName`.`p_refresh_table1`(12);
```

It does NOT update results to table1

I have found the reason behind this so if I expand the SQL in this procedure and manually pass the id I see the following :

The SQL is:

```
DELETE FROM  table1 where id=loc_id;
INSERT INTO selling table
                (column1,
                 column2,
                 column3,
..
..
.
)
       (SELECT DISTINCT table2.id,
..
..
..
..
);
```

If I run the sql with loc_id substituted with '12' **(quoted)** it works as expected
However If I run it with loc_id substituted with 12 **(unquoted)** it does not update table1.
So I need to know how I can pass '12' instead of 12 to the value of loc_id.

The procedure create statement starts like so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`userName`@`%` PROCEDURE `p_refresh_table1`(loc_id VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
      END;

      SET sql_log_off = 1;

      START TRANSACTION;
```

Thanks

Comment: Type quotes around it.

Comment: Where did you call procedure `p_refresh_table1`? How did you call it (show your code, in your program: Java, C#, php,....?)?

Comment: i called it like so "mysql> CALL databaseName.p_refresh_table1('12');" , I get the following output "Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)"

Comment: @Pham X. Bach please see the updated version of the question and my last comment